# A world without cash

Tags: currency

Imagine a world, exactly like ours, but from this point forward, we just stopped printing cash and making coins. Old and damaged notes would be taken out of circulation over time so naturally ATMs would become useless and after a certain amount of time, the old cash and coins will not be considered legal tender.

How would the country change? (if you pardon the pun)

Will the economy be effected?

Who would me the most severely impacted?

Will the criminal rings be damaged by this (since electronic transactions can be traced most of the time)?

Comment: You're going to need to scale this question down a bit and focus on more specific questions - as it stands we already discourage multiple questions per post, but the questions you ask are so broad as to fill whole books. I'm not sure any besides the middle two are truly answerable.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! You may want to read [this Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) in order to understand why your current question is too broad for this site. Please also take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about WorldBuilding.

Comment: Anything you want. Perhaps state your desired result and someone might justify why it could happen. But be prepared, there is always that one guy that writes why it's unlikely, if you don't want that answer 5 times, perhaps state so also

Comment: Across the world cashiers and people in grocery lines would rejoice, as they would no longer have to wait for someone to count out exact change from the depths of their purse. Truly a bright future.

Comment: The entire world stops using cash, or just one country?  There are a host of problems in trying to enforce the entire world, but just one country is relatively easy.

Comment: How was this implemented?  The world is going to go one way if some dictator demanded everyone use their new traceable electronic currency than if e-currencies like bit-coin achieve their goal of being untracable and take off, replacing cash worldwide.  It may also be amusing to look at what has happened in countries which removed their penny from circulation.  It's not quite the same, but the process might provide some real life hints as to where your nation might go.

Comment: Aunt Greta puts a $10 bill in every birthday card. I guess the kids must learn to live without....

Comment: Here is a very similar real-world scenario: https://www.bbc.com/news/business-43645676 . Children can get gift cards. Criminals will use currency from other countries/planets, or physical goods (gold, cigarettes, ammo. Maybe also gift cards, since they do not need small change.

Comment: Here is a very similar real-world scenario: https://www.bbc.com/news/business-43645676 . Children can get gift cards. Criminals will use currency from other countries/planets, or physical goods (gold, cigarettes, ammo. Maybe also gift cards, since they do not need small change.

Comment: Here is a very similar real-world scenario: https://www.bbc.com/news/business-43645676 . Children can get gift cards. Criminals will use currency from other countries/planets, or physical goods (gold, cigarettes, ammo. Maybe also gift cards, since they do not need small change.

Answer (score 1):

We already use [credit cards for most transactions more than cash](https://theconversation.com/australians-are-now-using-cards-more-often-than-cash-to-pay-for-things-81718), so it is not too far in the future where credit cards will be the default transaction type.

Since the floating of most currencies, physical money holds little value to virtual money in particular if interest can be collected on virtual money and inflation causes physical money to lose value.

Would the country change? Yes but not as drastically as you may think.

Who most severely impacted? Those that hold physical money (this is not the banks), most likely for instance people who save in physical instead of virtual money.

Will criminal rings be damaged? Probably only the 'small' ones - large criminal syndicates probably already use online bank accounts more than they do lots of cash.